# How do I analyze the cue tip at impact with a billiard ball?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, collision, contact-mechanics

this is not a homework problem, it is something I've been trying to understand in billiard physics (because I'm a big pool fan)

When we hit the cue ball off-center to impart spin, we still don't know exactly how the tip and ball interact during the tip-ball contact. There are models and papers on this subject already. Dr.Dave did one [analysis](https://billiards.colostate.edu/technical_proofs/new/TP_A-31.pdf)  assuming the tip and the impact point remain static during the entire contact period.

However, what I find confusing for this assumption is that, if the tip and impact point remain static throughout the impact, that means the impact point on the ball, at rest right before impact, needs to have an instantaneous jump in velocity, in the direction tangential to the normal direction (connecting impact point to the center of ball). This is because the tip approaches the impact point with some velocity, and this velocity can be decomposed into the direction normal to the ball, and tangential to the ball at impact point.

That being said, is it true that there has to be some slipping between the tip and the ball at the very beginning of the impact, in order for the ball surface to catch up to the tip, and for the tip to decelerate? This conclusion comes from another paper [Motions of a billiard ball after a cue stroke](https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.11232) on page 5, right after the sentence *Let us explain the collision process in the order of time.*

However, if this reasoning is correct, it is not visible even in high-speed footage like this one, which was shot at 10,000 fps. [the tip grabs the ball immediately](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OA1w-b9gDoQ)

I really appreciate any input on this since I'm so confused.

Comment: The cue flexes on impact. Imagine if you wish swatting a bowling ball with a leaf spring

Comment: Yes it flexes I agree. But is the force provided by the sliding friction between the ball and the tip? Because if the tip and ball stick together with no relative motion, there is no sideway flex to begin with, right?

Answer (score 0):

It may seem that slipping should happen because friction will be less than impulsive force (tangential to ball). However we should also note that the **frictional force will also be impulsive** as normal force is impulsive. There will be some slipping but it will be very less.

However in real life, things are not perfectly rigid. As you see in the video, the cue actually shears. Think of at as a near-inelastic collision (Which means that cue does not rebound and hit the ball again). The friction is still impulsive, however the **force that is tangential to the ball, it is less impulsive since the cue will deform now**. The layers of the cue has a spring-like force, which reduces the impulsiveness.
[image]
Therefore the static friction will be enough to prevent slipping.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! It does make more sense now since I've been trying to understand the slipping based on the assumption that the cue is rigid, which is not just by looking at the video!